# How to determine if the current test is last one in the current tests execution (JUnit 4)

Tags: java, junit, junit4, ui-automation

I need to call some methods once ALL tests from ALL classes are finished. I'm using TestWatcher to override the succeeded/failed methods, but there's no methods like "afterTestExecution". I know there's a class RunListener that has method testRunFinished, but I have conflicts between listeners when using those at the same time.

Comment: what conflicts are you getting? can you add more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shutdown hooks are basically initialized but unstarted threads. When the JVM begins its shutdown process, it will start all registered hooks.

Add a global tear down using a Java shutdown hook, add it any of your tests and in the clean() method add your cleanup code

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class Example {


    @Test
    public void first() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> clean()));
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
        System.out.println("First Executed");
    }

    @Test
    public void second() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, 2);
        System.out.println("Second Executed");
    }

    private void clean() {
        System.out.println("cleans");
    }
}
```

Output of below will be

```
First Executed
Second Executed
cleans
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Gradle, so that's not a case for me. I have solved it by putting the test classes into a single suite class and posted an @After annotation there.

Comment: @AdamJensen good to know but using gradle or maven shouldn't matter as Shutdown hook is Java construct